# Jdesktop or Qt for better Desktop application

Tags: qt, desktop-application, jdesktop

I will make a desktop application. I searched on web which one is better. Can someone say positive and negative sides of these components.

Answer (score 4):

I can add some information about QT:

QT is a well designed, portable library that covers nearly everything you'll need for a desktop application. QT covers GUI, networking, SQL, Graphics and more.

Pros:

- very extensive library
- high performance
- portable

Cons:

- It's C++
- special preprocessor / make tool needed.

Setting up a QT compile environment is a little bit more difficult than setting up a C++ compile environment. C++ is - especially if you are not used to it - very difficult and the learning curve is steep. QT helps alot with appropriate helper classes (QPointer, ...) and library magic (QObjects freeing children, ...) in the background. There are bindings to other languages as well. Just to mention a few - Jambi is a binding for Java and there's a binding for python as well.

For your decision consider the following things

- which programming language do you know best
- which libray reduces your amout of work for this application the most
- how much performance do you REALLY need. C++ code can be very fast, but there's no reason to work with manual memory management and pointers if you don't need the performance.
- which library offers you the look and feel you want to have for your desktop application
- If you need portability: Do you want to "compile once run everywhere" (Java) or do you want to "run your app everywhere once you compiled it for this plattform" (QT)

---

Here's the link to QT-Jambi Wiki: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-jambi/pages/Home. According to Nokia: "Qt Jambi is the Qt GUI toolkit for Java developers"

Comment: Is Jambi still being developed, or did they drop it?

Comment: I think they relying on community input for jambi now, iirc i saw something about this a couple of months ago, but i can't find the appropriate link. 

On a side note I would not call having to write c++ a 'con', it is as much of a con as something else written in java if you don't use java in general

Comment: Jambi was turned over to the community. It was developed by Nokia through v4.5. And if your developing in a JVM language, then its the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is the best cross platform GUI framework at the moment. It renders the widgets with a native look on each platform and it has a very easy to use API.

Using Qt doesn't mean that you have to use C++. You can program Qt in Java (Qt Jambi) or Python (PyQt) for instance.